# What is a good program to test server load with X number of users?

Tags: load

I have a PHP web application, and I want to test out the load when 100+ users are connected at the same time.  Is there a program out there that would allow 100+ virtual users to hit my webpage?

I did find one, but it was $3000.
I don't mind paying, but not quite that much.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772524/most-effective-and-realistic-free-web-app-load-tester

Answer (score 3):

Apache Bench is free, and runs on all flavors of *nix:

```
ab [ -b windowsize ] [ -c concurrency ] [ -C cookie-name=value ]  [
   -n requests ] http://www.example.com/page-to-test.html
```

Try:

```
man ab
```

I've found it works great when you just want to make sure you can handle a certain load.

For more complex load-balancing, spend the money.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with JMeter, which is open source.

100+ users each requiring how much memory?  You might need several machines to accommodate the desired load, but it's certainly doable.

Comment: +1 JMeter is a bit rough but properly used, it is just great (I like it especially because it's a Java tool, it can be "clustered" for big loads, tests can be easily automated, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You many need something more advanced, but a first approach may be suited for Http_load http://www.acme.com/software/http_load/

It is a basic script that spins up a bunch of threads and hits your website for a specified duration.  It reports back with some interesting statistics related to throughput and the number of successful responses.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the Client side processing, for example your app may use URL-rewriting as a method for tracking Sessions (as opposed to Cookies), so the simple url drivers may not work for you. That said for 100 'Virtual' users I would look into using a 'headless browser' approach. That is using Selenium Webdriver (or similar) to execute tests against actual Browsers (headless) then run multiple instances of these. You should be able to run about 25 headless Browsers in a small VM image (Amazon), you will need around 5 VMs. The big advantage of this approach, for small numbers of load, is that you don't need to worry about parsing the HTTP stream as the Browser API handles this. Also you can re-purpose Functional tests to become performance test assets.

Answer (score 0):

`siege` from http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/ is similiar to `ab`

Sample output available at https://gist.github.com/mikaelz/5687636

I have it from https://vimeo.com/13768954